# Access SQL: How do I group by a part of string after @?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a list of emails:

```
1elelje@apple.com
2sfhwef@banana.com
3odnwoaetge@peach.com
4oientao@apple.com
5ow@peach.com
```

How Do I group by @apple.com @banana.com @peach.com?
I am using MS Access...

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to extract the domain from an email.  This uses string functions:

```
select mid(email, instr(email, '@'), 100), count(*)
from t
group by mid(email, instr(email, '@'), 100);
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you very much! This is exactly what I am looking for.